# Problem Uploading to arduino nano (atmega 328p)

Tags: arduino-nano

I am using Arduino 1.8.1 and arduino nano (mega 328p) and ftdi driver.
In device manager it seems no problem, because it is detected as COM99. But it says a problem while uploading to the board as picture given.
Please Helpp..

[image: This error that make me crazy]

Comment: It looks like it found an invalid library in your Arduino installation. From the screenshot, though, it is not clear which. You could try de-installing the Arduino software and re-installing it.

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot with mostly irrelevant stuff and an incomplete error message? Why not copy paste the error here? There is an obvious button labeled "Copy error messages".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error in the end about the invalid library, it seems a configuration problem and not a communication problem.

Try:

- Close and reopen the Arduino IDE (and check again)
- Remove the library and add it again (in the Manage library options in the menu), close/reopen the Arduino IDE (and check again)
- Reinstall the Arduino IDE (and check again)